# How to troubleshoot dependencies not copying

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, .net-2.0, dependencies, compilation

I have an EXE project A, which references a class library project B (all in the same solution).  Project B has a reference to about 10 3rd party DLLs (from DevExpress).  All the referenced assemblies have `Copy Local` set to true.

When I build the entire solution, the resulting DLL from project B is copied into the bin/debug of project A.  However, none of the dependencies of project B get copied.

I looked in the Output window during compile and all looks good.  There aren't any errors.

How do I troubleshoot this?

Comment: ...probably a stupid question, but does your app run?

Comment: Yes it does.  But that's probably because all those assemblies are also in the GAC (e.g. 3rd party DLLs got installed there on setup).

Comment: Follow the deployment procedure as recommended by the tool vendor.  Here's one: http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/KB/p/A240.aspx

Comment: Maybe it's because the 3rd party Dlls were not changed?

Comment: If the assemblies are in the GAC, do you need a local copy of the DLL's?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that copy local is set to true for your reference of project B in project A.

Comment: @SnOrfus.  The reference has CopyLocal set to true.